# Timezone not available in python, but the system timezone is properly set

Tags: python, timezone

As specified in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime):

```
%Z -> Time zone name (no characters if no time zone exists).
```

According to date, my system has the time zone properly set:

```
gonvaled@pegasus ~ » date
Sat Sep 28 09:14:29 CEST 2013
```

But this test:

```
def test_timezone():
    from datetime import datetime
    dt = datetime.now()
    print dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%Z')   
test_timezone()
```

Produces:

```
gonvaled@pegasus ~ » python test_timezone.py 
2013-09-28 09:19:10
```

Without time zone information. Why is that? How can I force python to output time zone info?

I have also trying re-configuring the time zone with `tzselect`, but has not helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard Python `datetime.datetime()` objects do not have a timezone *object* attached to them. The system time is taken as is.

You'll need to install Python timezone support in the form of the [`pytz` package](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/); timezone definitions change too frequently to be bundled with Python itself.

`pytz` does not tell you what timezone your machine has been configured with. You can use the [`python-dateutil` module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil) for that; it has a [`dateutil.tz.gettz()` function](http://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-b79630fbbda87af6d6d121737510fd7ea5aeea97) that returns the timezone currently in use. This is much more reliable than what Python can get from the limited C API:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> from dateutil.tz import gettz
>>> datetime.datetime.now(gettz())
datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 28, 8, 34, 14, 680998, tzinfo=tzfile('/etc/localtime'))
>>> datetime.datetime.now(gettz()).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%Z')
'2013-09-28 08:36:01BST'
```

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation! I was not aware that the timezone object must be explicitly added.